# how do I get vertical bars to show up properly in tmux running in docker?

Tags: ssh, docker, tmux

I'm trying to use tmux inside of docker.  For the most part it works fine but if I split my main window into a left and right window, the bar that tmux should draw between the two windows is only partially drawn.  There are also some other window rendering problems but that's the first one that I notice and easiest to describe.

Here's the Dockerfile that I use to build my test image:

```
FROM ubuntu:wily

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tmux
```

And this is the command I use to start docker with tmux:

```
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint tmux imageName
```

My host machine is running Ubuntu 15.04 and I'm running docker from a terminal with TERM=xterm .   Inside the docker container, TERM=screen

If I start sshd instead of tmux then I can log into the running container with ssh and use tmux from within the ssh session without problems.  This is what I have been doing until now but it seems unnecessarily messy.

What can I do to get the windows to draw correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a similar issue on the tmux project ([issue 224)](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/224)

The solution there was:

```
set -ag terminal-overrides ',*:cud1=\E[1B'
```

Added in  `.tmux.conf` file (for example ~/.tmux.conf).

You also have [docker/issues/8755](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755) which is about the proper tty to have when running a tmux session.

```
docker exec -ti $CONTAINER_NAME tty
not a tty
```

> And again, the workaround:

```
docker exec -ti $CONTAINER_NAME script -qc 'tty' /dev/null
/dev/pts/0
```

Finally, [issue 5379](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5379#issuecomment-60305012) mentions:

> with the env var set to `screen-256color` it worked. Couldn't find any other `$TERM` that did that trick though (tried some like `xterm-256color`).

That implies running docker run with `-e TERM=screen-256color` option.

Comment: I think the "similar issue on the tmux project" was exactly the same thing.  Same symptoms and same solution worked

Comment: Windows Terminal = ssh => K8s linux tmux

This fixed the issue for me:
`set -ag terminal-overrides ',*:cud1=\E[1B'`

Comment: @ini Well done: that seems to be the exact `set -ag` mentioned in the answer, but, as you said, working from a Windows Terminal SSH session.